# How To Get All Items Created or Still Open For A Given Time

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am working with a system were items are created (`postDate` dimension) and closed (`endDate` dimension). The `endDate` column is always populated with the last time the item was seen. An item is considered closed in a certain time if its last seen date is before the date you are querying. Each row in the fact table has the item, `postDate`, `endDate`, `locationID`, and some other dimensions used for aggregations. What I am trying to accomplish is getting all items still active for a given time frame. For example I want to know all items posted in November 2008 or before November 2008 that has not yet closed. In SQL it would look something like:

```
SELECT C.geoCountyArea,TM.CalendarYear,COUNT(DISTINCT a.itemid)
FROM [dbo].[factTable] a
JOIN dbo.dimDate AS TM
    ON TM.DateKey BETWEEN postDate AND endDate
JOIN [dbo].[dim_geography] C
    ON A.geographyID=C.geographyID
WHERE C.geoCountyArea = '1204000057'
AND TM.CalendarYear = 2008 AND TM.MonthNumberOfYear = 11
GROUP BY C.geoCountyArea,TM.CalendarYear
ORDER BY C.geoCountyArea,TM.CalendarYear
```

This returns `27,715` which is expected. Now, in MDX this looks like:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[itemCount] AS
    AGGREGATE(
        {NULL:[PostDate].[Month Name].&[2008]&[11]} * {[EndDate].[Month Name].&[2008]&[11]:NULL},
        [Measures].[Fact_itemCount]
    )

SELECT NON EMPTY (
    Measures.[itemCount]
    ) ON 0,
NON EMPTY (
    {[PostDate].[Month Name].&[2008]&[11]},
    {[Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]}
    )ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

This returns `27,717` - which is 2 more than the SQL version that could be due to items with no end Date posted. Now, the complication comes when I want to get more than one explicit time - for example item count for all months in 2008 or item count for all years. I looked up methods to link a given param to another one via roll playing dimensions and came across [this](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/) link. I altered my script so it looks like:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[itemCount] AS
    AGGREGATE( 
          {NULL:LINKMEMBER([DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
                     ,[PostDate].[Calendar])}
        * {LINKMEMBER([DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
                    , [EndDate].[Calendar]):NULL}
        , [Measures].[Fact_itemCount]
        )

SELECT {Measures.[jobCount]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY (
    {[DATE].[Month Name].&[2008]&[11]},
    {[Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]}
    )ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

This, however, returns only the items created in November 2008 - value of `14,884`. If I add in other months I do get individual counts for each month but, again, these are just the items created in those months.

How do I get the "active" item count for a given month/year/quarter without having do explicitly declare the time values in the `AGGREGATE`?

Comment: Is the dimension "date" related with either "post Date" or "end date"?

Comment: @SouravA, yes. `Date` is a dimension used by both `postDate` and `endDate`. However, if you query the cube just on `Date` dimension it treats it like `postDate` (similar to most Adventure Works examples).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `NonEmpty`?

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[itemCount] AS
    AGGREGATE( 
          {NULL:
             NONEMPTY(
               [PostDate].[Month Name].MEMBERS //<<AMEND TO EXACT STRUCTURE USED IN YOUR CUBE
              ,[DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
             ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)}
        * {NONEMPTY(
               [EndDate].[Month Name].MEMBERS //<<AMEND TO EXACT STRUCTURE USED IN YOUR CUBE
              ,[DATE].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER
             ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0): NULL}
        , [Measures].[Fact_itemCount]
        )
...
```

Comment: This was throwing an error: `#Error Query (6, 5) The MEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the  argument. A member expression was used.` Then I fixed the dimension text formatting - now it is running, but has not yet completed (2 minutes and counting).

Comment: @wergeld did it complete with the correct answer? (it has had a couple of months now ...!)

Comment: No, This never returned a valid result. It only returned the counts for items created in a month and did not include those items still active for the month requested.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution that provided valid results (tested against SQL calls against the warehouse tables):

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[itemCount] AS
    AGGREGATE(
        {NULL:LINKMEMBER([Post Date].[Calendar],
            [Post Date].[Calendar])}
        * {LINKMEMBER([Post Date].[Calendar],
            [End Date].[Calendar]):NULL},
        [Measures].[Fact_itemCount]
    )

SELECT {Measures.[itemCount]} ON 0,
NON EMPTY (
    {[Post Date].[Month Name].Children},
    {[Geography].[Geo County Area].&[1204000057]}
    )
FROM [Cube]
```

Not that I am doing `LINKMEMBER` against the post and end dates - not against the global Date measure.